# Interpolation of values when zooming down

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, zooming, interpolation

I have a 2D array that I would like to down sample to compare it to another.

Lets say my array `x` is `512x512`, I'd like an array `y` `128x128` where the elements of `y` are build using an interpolation of the values overs `4x4` blocks of `x` (this interpolation could just be taking the average, but other methodes, like geometric average, could be interesting)

So far I looked at `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom` but I don't get the results I want

```
>> x = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
>> print(x)
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
>> y = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(x, 0.5)
>> print(y)
[[ 0  3]
 [12 15]]
```

I expected `y` to be

```
[[ 2.5  4.5]
 [10.5 12.5]]
```

Note that simply setting `dtype=np.float32` doesn't solve that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is the mean over blocks of 4, which is not obtainable with `zoom`, since `zoom` uses interpolation (see its docstring)

To obtain what you show, try the following

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)

xx = x.reshape(len(x) // 2, 2, x.shape[1] // 2, 2).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(len(x) // 2, x.shape[1] // 2, -1).mean(-1)

print xx
```

This yields

```
[[  2.5   4.5]
 [ 10.5  12.5]]
```

Alternatively, this can be done using `sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches

patches = extract_patches(x, patch_shape=(2, 2), extraction_step=(2, 2))

xx = patches.mean(-1).mean(-1)

print xx
```

However, if your goal is to subsample an image in a graceful way, then taking the mean over blocks of the image is *not* the right way to do it: It is likely to cause aliasing effects. What you should do in this case is smooth the image ever so slightly using `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` (e.g. `sigma=0.35 * subsample_factor`) and then subsample simply by indexing `[::2, ::2]`

Comment: I'd like this operation to compare scientific data at different sampling level ... not to process images in the conventional way

Therefore I don't know if applying a gaussian filter whould be a good thing or not in my case. I'll keep it in mind

Comment: All the rules of sampling then still apply right? Aliasing is not image specific but can happen with any continuous signal that you try to approximate with discrete measurements. Averaging adjacent values corresponds to multiplying with a `sinc` type function in fourier space, which has infinite support and doesn't decrease well, whereas gaussian smoothing, despite its infinite support, is at least rapidly decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

`sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches` cleverly uses `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to produce a *windowed* array that can be operated on.

The `sliding_window` function, found here
[Efficient Overlapping Windows with Numpy](http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268),  produces a windowed array with or without overlap
also and let's you get a glimpse of what is happening under the hood.

```
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
```

`step_height,step_width` determines the overlap for the windows - in your case the steps are the same as the window size, no overlap.

```
>>> window_height, window_width, step_height, step_width = 2, 2, 2, 2
>>> y = sliding_window(a, (window_height, window_width), (step_height,step_width))
>>> y
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 2,  3],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [12, 13]],

       [[10, 11],
        [14, 15]]])
```

Operate on the windows:

```
>>> y = y.mean(axis = (1,2))
>>> y
array([  2.5,   4.5,  10.5,  12.5])
```

You need to determine the final shape depending on the number of windows.

```
>>> final_shape = (2,2)
>>> y = y.reshape(final_shape)
>>> y
array([[  2.5,   4.5],
       [ 10.5,  12.5]])
```

Searching SO for `numpy`, window, array should produce numerous other answers and possible solutions.